# How to include both C and C++ files in makefile directives

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, g++

The following part is commonly found in makefiles.

```
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(DEFS) $(CFLAGS) -o$@ $<
```

Now my source folder contains both C and C++ files, and I want to link all object files created together using g++. But how do I specify to also also include *.cpp files to get compiled. I mean how do I modify OBJS to also include *.cpp files.

For OBJDIR, maybe, I can do the C++ equivalent like this. I guess the makefile would guess correctly when to use CXX (g++ for C++ files) and when to use CC (gcc for C files).

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(DEFS) $(CFLAGS) -o$@ $<
```

But then, how do I add this rule to OBJS?

Comment: I believe you can just specify two rules (i.e. `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c ... $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp ...`).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more. If I have $(OBJDIR_CXX/%.o for C++, and $(OBJDIR)/%.o for C, how do I modify OBJS here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need a rule for building .o files from corresponding .cpp or .c files at all, as Make comes with default rules for that, and those look a lot like what you present.  The key is probably to specify which `.o` files need to be built in the first place.

I often see that approached by classifying the C sources separately from the C++ sources.  Then you might have something like this:

```
C_SRCS = ...
CPP_SRCS = ...

OBJS = $(C_SRCS:.c=.o) $(CPP_SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: myprog

myprog: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

If you do need your own rules for building `.o` files from sources, then you could of course add those.

Note also that the above has no dependencies on GNU make extensions, and if that's important to you then you'll want to avoid GNU style pattern rules for building the object files.  That's what traditional suffix rules are for.

Comment: But aren't you here compiling every file with g++. I want to compile C files with gcc and C++ files with g++, and then link them together using g++.

Comment: No, @pythonic, I am not compiling every file with `g++`.  I am *linking* the program with g++, and relying on Make's built-in rules to compile each needed .o file from the corresponding .c or .cpp file, using the compilation rule appropriate to the source file type.

Comment: @pythonic, but as I updated the answer to say, you can add rules for .c to .o and .cpp to .o if you need or want to do.  Make chooses the appropriate rule based not only on the needed *target*, but also on the available *sources*.

Comment: So, you mean, If I place all my object files in a directory (lets say OBJDIR), can I write the rule $(OBJDIR)/%.o 2 times, one for C, and another for C++, as written in my question?

Comment: @pythonic, yes, that is a viable option.  Make's default rules will put the .o files alongside the corresponding sources, so if you want to put them in a different directory instead then that would be a good reason to add your own rules (two of them) for building the .o files.  You'll then also want to construct the value of the `OBJS` variable differently (to include the path); you might do that with a GNU-style pattern substitution.

Comment: @pythonic, I would do that via .c.o: and .cpp.o: suffix rules and just prepend the object directory to the target output.

Comment: No @diverscuba23, you cannot (should not) do it via suffix rules if you want the output to go to a different directory, because then your recipe fails to build the targets it promises to build.

Comment: You do not want to use `$(C_SRCS:.c=.o) $(CPP_SRCS:.cpp=.o)` as that will result in `OBJS` containing both all the .o files AND all the .c and .cpp files.  Then because you use `$^` you will add all those files to the link line, which will give you errors.

Comment: @MadScientist, umm, no, it won't, supposing that `$(C_SRCS)` contains only the names of C source files, ending with `.c`, and `$(CPP_SRCS)` contains only the names of C++ source files, ending with `.cpp`, as the names are meant to imply.  That's largely the point of having those as separate variables.

Comment: Oh I see.  No real need to keep them separate though... just adds cognitive overhead.  They all get turned into .o files.

Comment: @MadScientist, of course there's a reason to keep them separate: to facilitate forming the `OBJS` list without relying on GNU extensions, exactly as I demonstrate.  Or if you're OK with GNU extensions, then it may be convenient to have them separate to facilitate using the `$(wildcard)` function to initialize them.

Comment: OK.  Note that POSIX make doesn't define `$^` so if portability is your goal you can't use that either.

Comment: Fair point, @MadScientist.  That can easily be addressed by repeating `$(OBJS)` in the recipe instead.  Since I seem to be taking the portability angle, I will shortly make that change in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use:

```
OBJS := $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRCS)))
```

then add your pattern rule for building `.o` from `.cpp` (unless, as mentioned here, you can just use the built-in rules).

The above strips off the suffix, regardless of what it is, then adds `.o` to the end.

Comment: This missing a ')'. However when I trying to edit, the site tell me I must edit at least 6 characters.